# twocolumn / IEEEtran vertical alignment of columns

Tags: floats, ieeetran

I'm currently writing a paper using the IEEEtran class (which uses the twocolumn option).
When inserting this float figur, it is properly placed, but the second column is also aligned vertically with the first one, leaving an ugly gap. Two underfull vbox errors are also thrown (PDFLatex). What could lead to this behavior? How can I further analyze this problem?

Example:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[pdftex,demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[8]

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{}
   \caption{\small Test}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: don't do `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,height=10cm]{myNiceFigure}` if you specify width and height the figure will distort unless you use `keepaapctratio` and `.5\textwidth is too wide (because of `\olumnsep`) use `\linewidth` or `\columnwidth`

Comment: I suggest `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` respectively, unless you want some additional vertical spacing above and below the figure.

Comment: The output looks like you used `figure*` rather than `figure` please (always) make a _complete_ small document that shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, both the centering and the textwidth issue was new to me!

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment, thus posted as an "answer"...

The following should work, i.e., produce a float that's as wide as a single column. Note that there's no need to use a `center` environment if you make the graph as wide as possible given the available space (which equals `\columnwidth`). Don't use `0.5\textwidth` to specify the width, since a column is *less wide* than 0.5\textwidth.

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{myNiceFigure}
    \caption{\small Caption Text}
    \label{fig:myNiceFigure}
\end{figure}
```